# How can I disable error messages in SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services)?

Tags: .net, xml, reporting-services, web-config

Struggling with unfriendly SSRS error messages. Tried various web solutions, but no luck. Seeking help to customize error handling and display user-friendly pages for report not found & other errors. See image:
[image: screenshot] Appreciate your expertise. Thanks!

Comment: SQL database (MDF file) must be installed on the same physical drive as the server.  So Server can be installed on the c: drive and database on the d: drive.  But not on a E: Network drive.  Your error message indicates the Report Viewer path is over 260 character long which usually means it is on a remote machine.  Also error indicates the path may not start with a backslash d:\myFolder